# Highcharts - Fix chart height when it has legends

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to make the aspect of a chart the same, independent of legends quantity? What I mean is, following the examples below, we can see that as the number of legends grow the chart becomes smaller.

Can I disable this kind of behavior?

[image: First chart]

First chart, that has a good aspect.

[image: Second chart]

Second chart, that has a not so good aspect.

Comment: Have you tried Highcharts' "responsive mode"? https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/responsive it moves the labels to bottom or the side depending on how much room the chart has. And this jsfiddle is a good example (from the same url): https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/responsive/legend

Comment: I didn't know the responsive mode, thank you for the tip. Actually, I managed to implement the chart in a better looking way using the `scrollable-plotarea-vertical` option.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to implement it in a better way using the [scrollable-plotarea-vertical option](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.scrollablePlotArea).

Though it solved my problem, it only works on Highcharts v7.1.2 and above.